# Bitmap parceling

Tags: android, bitmap

When trying to save a bitmap to parcel I get this

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Tried to marshall a Parcel that contained Binder objects.
at android.os.Parcel.marshall(Native Method)
```

Does anyone know why?

Comment: How do you save a bitmap to parcel? Can you post some code?

Comment: I got this problem as well could you find a solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

Bitmap has already parcelled by android

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#writeToParcel(android.os.Parcel

also see this question:
[How To: Parcel a bitmap in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7326365/how-to-parcel-a-bitmap-in-android)