# Error writing serializable object (bitmap include)

Tags: android, serialization, bitmap, android-imageview, serializable

I want save a Contacto's item on a RecyclerView from a NewContact class by intent. In my Contactos class I have a Bitmap and I know this is the error becuase, before, without bitmap works it. What's wrong?

Contactos class:

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Contactos implements Serializable{
private String Nombre;
private String Apellidos;
private String Telefono;
private String Correo;
private Bitmap Foto;


public Contactos(){

}
public Contactos(String nombre, String apellidos, String telefono, String correo) {
    Nombre = nombre;
    Apellidos = apellidos;
    Telefono = telefono;
    Correo = correo;

}

public Contactos(String nombre, String apellidos, String telefono, String correo, Bitmap foto) {
    Nombre = nombre;
    Apellidos = apellidos;
    Telefono = telefono;
    Correo = correo;
    Foto = foto;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return Nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    Nombre = nombre;
}

public String getApellidos() {
    return Apellidos;
}

public void setApellidos(String apellidos) {
    Apellidos = apellidos;
}

public String getTelefono() {
    return Telefono;
}

public void setTelefono(String telefono) {
    Telefono = telefono;
}

public String getCorreo() {
    return Correo;
}

public void setCorreo(String correo) {
    Correo = correo;
}

public Bitmap getFoto() {
    return Foto;
}

public void setFoto(Bitmap foto) {
    Foto = foto;
}

}
```

and Holder class:

```
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
TextView txtnombre;
TextView txtapellido;
TextView txttelefono;
TextView txtemail;
ImageView iVFoto;

public Holder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    txtnombre = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtNombre);
    txtapellido  = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtApellidos);
    txttelefono  = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtTelefono);
    txtemail = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtCorreo);
    iVFoto = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.foto);
}

public void bind(Contactos c){
    txtnombre.setText(c.getNombre());
    txtapellido.setText(c.getApellidos());
    txttelefono.setText(c.getTelefono());
    txtemail.setText(c.getCorreo());
    //iVFoto.setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), c.getFoto())); me marca en ROJO getResources() y me pone que está en desuso(tachado) BitmapDrawable
    iVFoto.setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(c.getFoto()));

}

public TextView getTxtnombre() {
    return txtnombre;
}

public TextView getTxtapellido() {
    return txtapellido;
}

public TextView getTxttelefono() {
    return txttelefono;
}

public TextView getTxtemail() {
    return txtemail;
}

public ImageView getiVFoto() {
    return iVFoto;
}
}
```

And the logcat

```
11-06 10:04:48.185  28245-28245/com.example.jorge.ejerciciopropuestoagenda E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.jorge.ejerciciopropuestoagenda, PID: 28245
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = com.example.jorge.ejerciciopropuestoagenda.Contactos)
            at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1394)
            at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1341)
            at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:644)
            at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1313)
            at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1034)
            at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:669)
            at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:7496)
            at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.finishActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:2725)
            at android.app.Activity.finish(Activity.java:4662)
            at android.app.Activity.finish(Activity.java:4680)
            at com.example.jorge.ejerciciopropuestoagenda.NuevoContacto.onClick(NuevoContacto.java:55)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4785)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19884)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
     Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: android.graphics.Bitmap
            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1344)
            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1651)
            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1497)
            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1461)
            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFieldValues(ObjectOutputStream.java:959)
            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:360)
            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1054)
            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1384)
            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1651)
            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1497)
            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1461)
            at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1389)
            at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1341)
            at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:644)
            at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1313)
            at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1034)
            at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:669)
            at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:7496)
            at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.finishActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:2725)
            at android.app.Activity.finish(Activity.java:4662)
            at android.app.Activity.finish(Activity.java:4680)
            at com.example.jorge.ejerciciopropuestoagenda.NuevoContacto.onClick(NuevoContacto.java:55)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4785)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19884)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
```

Answer (score 3):

> Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: android.graphics.Bitmap

So Bitmap is not a serializable object. You can add the keyword `transient` in order to tell java to not serialize it

```
private transient Bitmap Foto;
```

From this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910374/why-does-java-have-transient-variables)

> The transient keyword in Java is used to indicate that a field should not be serialized.

Also you should think about using `Parcelable` instead of `Serializable` when you use Android (see this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323074/android-difference-between-parcelable-and-serializable) and the [doc](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html))

Using `Parcelable` you can store/retrieve Bitmap using (from [here]'[How To: Parcel a bitmap in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7326365/how-to-parcel-a-bitmap-in-android)))

```
//Store
Parcel parcel = Parcel.obtain();
Bitmap sourceBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(200, 400, Config.ARGB_8888);
sourceBitmap.writeToParcel(parcel, 0);

//Retrieve
parcel.setDataPosition(0);
Bitmap destinationBitmap = Bitmap.CREATOR.createFromParcel(parcel);
```

Answer (score 0):

For using Serializable is not support Bitmap, if your using Serializable you need to convert that into

```
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90,outputStream);
```

Otherwise its better to use Parcelable:

```
public class Contactos implements Parcelable {

    private String Nombre;
    private String Apellidos;
    private String Telefono;
    private String Correo;
    private Bitmap Foto;

    public Contactos() {

    }

    public Contactos(String nombre, String apellidos, String telefono, String correo) {
        Nombre = nombre;
        Apellidos = apellidos;
        Telefono = telefono;
        Correo = correo;
    }

    public Contactos(String nombre, String apellidos, String telefono, String correo, Bitmap foto) {
        Nombre = nombre;
        Apellidos = apellidos;
        Telefono = telefono;
        Correo = correo;
        Foto = foto;
    }

    protected Contactos(Parcel in) {
        Nombre = in.readString();
        Apellidos = in.readString();
        Telefono = in.readString();
        Correo = in.readString();
        Foto = in.readParcelable(Bitmap.class.getClassLoader());
    }

    public static final Creator<Contactos> CREATOR = new Creator<Contactos>() {
        @Override
        public Contactos createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Contactos(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Contactos[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Contactos[size];
        }
    };

    public String getNombre() {
        return Nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        Nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getApellidos() {
        return Apellidos;
    }

    public void setApellidos(String apellidos) {
        Apellidos = apellidos;
    }

    public String getTelefono() {
        return Telefono;
    }

    public void setTelefono(String telefono) {
        Telefono = telefono;
    }

    public String getCorreo() {
        return Correo;
    }

    public void setCorreo(String correo) {
        Correo = correo;
    }

    public Bitmap getFoto() {
        return Foto;
    }

    public void setFoto(Bitmap foto) {
        Foto = foto;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(Nombre);
        dest.writeString(Apellidos);
        dest.writeString(Telefono);
        dest.writeString(Correo);
        dest.writeParcelable(Foto, flags);
    }
}
```

Hope its work for you.